# Error while trying to generate xml file with specific name

Tags: python, xml

I tried to generate a file named, for example, 23-10-2022|21-03-11.xml or if the user enters his own name userGeneratedName23-10-2022-21-03-11.xml. I don't know why when I tried to specify a particular folder where the generated file should be saved the program throws me an Invalid argument error. I suspect that I am using join incorrectly, I don't really know how to correct it

```
    if not os.path.exists("Generated XMLs"):
        os.makedirs("Generated XMLs")
    #open file
    today = date.today()
    now = datetime.now()
    #if filename is not specified, create file with today's date and time of creation
    if filename == "":
        filename = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") +"|"+ now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    #if filename is specified,ad at the and of filename today's date and time of creation
    else:
        filename = filename + today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+"|"+ now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    # open file wchich is in Generated XMLs folder and name it with variable filename
    file = open(os.path.join("Generated XMLs", filename + ".xml"), "w")
    #write to file

    #write header
    file.write("\n<root>\n<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>")
    file.write("\t<POZYCJE>\n")
    #write data
    # ask user if he wont netto or brutto meters and ad flag
    flag = input("Enter 'n' if you want to use netto meters or 'b' if you want to use brutto meters: ")
    for i in range(len(convertedData)):

        file.write("\t\t<POZYCJA>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<LP>" + (i+1) + "</LP>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<TOWAR>\n")

        file.write("\t\t\t\t<KOD>" + convertedData[i][0] + " " + convertedData[i][1] + "</KOD>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<NAZWA>" + convertedData[i][0] + " " + convertedData[i][1] + "</NAZWA>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<OPIS/>")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<EAN/>")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<SWW/>")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<NUMER_KATALOGOWY/>")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<MPP>" + "0" + "</MPP>\n")

        file.write("\t\t\t</TOWAR>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<STAWKA_VAT>\n")

        file.write("\t\t\t\t<STAWKA>" + "23.00" + "</STAWKA>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<FLAGA>" + "2" + "</FLAGA>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<ZRODLOWA>" + "0.00" + "</ZRODLOWA>\n")

        file.write("\t\t\t</STAWKA_VAT>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<CENY>\n")

        file.write("\t\t\t\t<CENAZCZTEREMAMIEJSCAMI>0</CENAZCZTEREMAMIEJSCAMI>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<POCZATKOWA_WAL_CENNIKA>00.0000</POCZATKOWA_WAL_CENNIKA>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<POCZATKOWA_WAL_DOKUMENTU>00.0000</POCZATKOWA_WAL_DOKUMENTU>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<PO_RABACIE_WAL_CENNIKA>00.0000</PO_RABACIE_WAL_CENNIKA>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<PO_RABACIE_PLN>00.0000</PO_RABACIE_PLN>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<PO_RABACIE_WAL_DOKUMENTU>00.0000</PO_RABACIE_WAL_DOKUMENTU>\n")

        file.write("\t\t\t</CENY>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<WALUTA>\n")

        file.write("\t\t\t\t<SYMBOL>PLN</SYMBOL>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<KURS_L>1.00</KURS_L>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t<KURS_M>1</KURS_M>\n")

        file.write("\t\t\t</WALUTA>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<RABAT>0.00</RABAT>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<WARTOSC_NETTO>0.00</WARTOSC_NETTO>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<WARTOSC_BRUTTO>0.00</WARTOSC_BRUTTO>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<WARTOSC_NETTO_WAL>00.00</WARTOSC_NETTO_WAL>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<WARTOSC_BRUTTO_WAL>833.94</WARTOSC_BRUTTO_WAL>\n")
        if flag == "n":
            file.write("\t\t\t<ILOSC>" + convertedData[i][3] + "00" + "</ilosc>\n")
        elif flag == "b":
            file.write("\t\t\t<ILOSC>" + convertedData[i][2] + "00" + "</ilosc>\n")
        else:
            print("Error: Wrong flag. Enter 'n' or 'b'.")
        file.write("\t\t\t<JB>" + convertedData[i][4] + "</JB>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<JM_CALKOWITE>0.00</JM_CALKOWITE>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<JM_ZLOZONA>\n")

        file.write("\t\t\t\t\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t\t\n")

        file.write("\t\t\t</JM_ZLOZONA>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<JMZ>" + convertedData[i][4] + "</JMZ>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<JM_PRZELICZNIK_L>1.00</JM_PRZELICZNIK_L>\n")
        file.write("\t\t\t<JM_PRZELICZNIK_M>1</JM_PRZELICZNIK_M>\n")
        file.write("\t\t</POZYCJA>\n")



    #write footer
    file.write("\t</POZYCJE>\n")
    file.write("</root>")
    #close file
    file.close()
```

The exact error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\reczul\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\reczul\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\main.py", line 13, in main
    XMLCreator.CreateXML(DataConverter.ConvertData(data))
  File "C:\Users\reczul\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\venv\Functions\XMLCreator.py", line 20, in CreateXML
    file = open(os.path.join("Generated XMLs", filename + ".xml"), "w")
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'Generated XMLs\\24-10-2022|09-23-45.xml'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: use https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html in order to generate xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not use "|" also I had to convert filename to str.

```
    if not os.path.exists("Generated XMLs"):
        os.makedirs("Generated XMLs")
    #open file
    today = date.today()
    now = datetime.now()
    #if filename is not specified, create file with today's date and time of creation
    if filename == "":
        filename = today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y") +"--"+ now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    #if filename is specified,ad at the and of filename today's date and time of creation
    else:
        filename = filename + today.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+"--"+ now.strftime("%H-%M-%S")
    filename = str(filename)
    # open file wchich is in Generated XMLs folder and name it with variable filename
    #file = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),"Generated XMLs",filename + ".xml"), "w")
    #cerate XML file which is in Generated XMLs folder
    file = open(os.path.join("Generated XMLs", filename + ".xml"), "w")
```